# How to print list of strings in reverse lexicographical order?

Tags: python

I need to write code that takes a user input, convert it to lowercase, then outputs it in reverse lexicographical order; Hence, "Paris in the Spring" becomes "the spring paris in"

Here's what I have so far:

```py
inStr = input("Enter a string: ")

# convert to lower case
lowStr = inStr.lower()
# split string into list items
listStr = lowStr.split()
# sort lexicographical order
listStr.sort()

print("Output: ", " ".join(listStr))
```

I just need to reverse the order of the output. Thanks!

Comment: `listStr.sort(reverse=True)`, that does reverse sort

Comment: @python_user, this worked perfectly, can't believe it was this easy. Thank you!